# Engineering graphics for robotics

Tags: design, robotics

I am intrigued by robotics and wish to pursue it with a fundamental approach. Could you recommend some valuable courses, links, or books that can help me begin my journey in engineering graphics?

Comment: Engineering graphics like CAD (Engineering Design Graphics) or computer vision?  Either way, start with geometry.  You need to know your way around a 3D cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: @Abel I need this for robot design probably its CAD. Any good course for CAD?Imagine am good at geometry

Comment: Try your local library, or second hand book shops. SO many books about drawing fundamentals etc